# Trying to send email to all people in a list in a SharePoint workflow 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-list

I am trying to send a email to each person in a SharePoint list in a workflow. The list includes a column for the email. It doesn't matter if I send one email to all the people in the list or a email to each member, but I need everyone to receive a email. The site is using 2010 workflows. Is there a way to do this in designer 2010?

Answer (score 0):

See Sending Emails with SPD2013 here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8d9608c4-bfc4-430b-b8d2-e967ded76775/send-email-from-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow?forum=sharepointdevelopment

You can definitely do this. What is triggering the Workflow? You should be able to reference the column when creating the emails.

Comment: When a item is added or changed.

Comment: Hi @jim Le Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Sorry! Noted for future reference.

Comment: @JimLe The site isn't configured to use 2013 workflows. Therefore, I can't use the solution you suggested. Do you know any way to do it in 2010 workflows?